# how to detect if input is stdin or not using python click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

Consider the following code:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument("file", type=click.File())
def cli(file):
   print(file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Executing as:

```
$ python ./cmd.py -
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
$ touch '<stdin>'
$ python ./cmd.py '<stdin>'
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

There is suprising difference in encoding.

How can I detect if the input was actual `-` and not anything else in python click?

Comment: `'<stdin>'` doesn't means file but special object  `sys.stdin` but you run `touch <stdin>` to create file. So maybe you should check if your `file` is `sys.stdin`. Besides every opened file has number and `sys.stdin` has `0`, `sys.stdout` has `1`, and `sys.sterr` has `2` - you can check `sys.stdin.fileno()` and maybe even `file.fileno()`

Comment: files have also function `isatty()` - `sys.stdout.isatty()` or `file.isatty()` which inform if this object is connected with console/terminal.

Comment: `utf-8` and `UTF-8` is the same encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'<stdin>'` doesn't means filename but special object `sys.stdin`

And you can compare `file == sys.stdin`

---

Every opened file has number which system uses to work with this opened file and `sys.stdin` also has this number.

Normally

- `sys.stdin.fileno()`  is `0`,
- `sys.stdout.fileno()` is `1`,
- `sys.sterr.fileno()`  is `2`

So you can compare `file.fileno() == 0`

---

`sys.stdin` is usually also assigned to `console`/`terminal` but normal file is not assigned - and you can check it with `.isatty()`

So you can compare `file.isatty() is False`

But this is not good method because sometimes `sys.stdin` is not assigned - ie.

- when it runs in script without access to terminal - like in `cron`
- when it works in `pipe` like `echo "text" | script.py` (but it will be it can be assigned when it is first in `pipe` like `script.py | sort`

But this method can be useful when you want to draw colored text on screen and send not colored text to file. But this may need to check also `sys.stdout`.

---

```
import click
import sys

@click.command()
@click.argument("file", type=click.File())
def cli(file):
   print('file  :', file)
   print('number:', file.fileno())
   print('  ==  :', file == sys.stdin)
   print('isatty:', file.isatty())
   print('stdin :', sys.stdin.isatty())
   print('stdout:', sys.stdout.isatty())   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

```
$ python3 ./cmd.py -

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
number: 0
 ==   : True
isatty: True
```

```
$ python3 ./cmd.py cmd.py

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='cmd.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
number: 3
 ==   : False
isatty: False
```

Comment: `sys.stdin.isatty()` is certainly false when stdin is a pipe, or a regular file, or otherwise not a TTY; and you can also expect it to be false in the cronjob case. It's _possible_ to configure a systemd service to have a direct file handle on a TTY, but it takes deliberate work (by default, stdin is `/dev/null`, and stdout and stderr are non-TTY handles that are attached to journald).

Comment: (Mind, in the `script.py | sort` case, it's _stdout_ that's not a TTY; stderr is typically what you want to be checking when you want to know if there's likely to be a human reading your log messages, or if you can put color codes in them or the like)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was checking example to confirm it: When  I run `script.py | sort` then it shows me `True` but when it as second item in pipe `echo "Hello" | script.py | sort` then it shows `False` - so all this depends on position.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was check only `stdin` but I should also check `stdout` in piping :) So all depends on position in pipe. if script is first in pipe then `stdin` is `True` but `stdout` is `False`. When it is last in pipe then `stdin` is `False` and `stdout` is `True`. And when it between two pipes then both are `False` - so all as you said. BTW: When I was writing about `isatty` I was also thinking about colored output on console, and not colored output to file :)